# Slow query with where and index on some fields

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index-tuning

I'm working on a project with the PostgreSQL 12 database.
I have a table of about 500 MB.
The structure of the table is as follows:

```
create table table_name
(
    id serial not null
        constraint table_name_pkey
            primary key,
    rejected_at timestamp,
    reserved_until timestamp,
    reserved_id integer,
    deleted_at timestamp,
    accepted_at timestamp
);
```

For the following query:

```
select *
from table_name
where rejected_at is null and (
        reserved_until is null or
        reserved_until <= '2021-05-14 14:23:16'
    )
  and deleted_at is null
```

I defined the indexes:

```
create index table_name_deleted_at_index
    on table_name (deleted_at);

create index table_name_rejected_at_deleted_at_index
    on table_name (rejected_at, deleted_at);

create index table_name_reserved_until_index
    on table_name (reserved_until);
```

But it has a very low performance. What can I do to improve performance?

The result of the explain analysis:

```
Index Scan using table_name_deleted_at_index on table_name  (cost=0.42..3827.19 rows=15697 width=936) (actual time=106.780..261.118 rows=1534 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (deleted_at IS NULL)
  Filter: ((rejected_at IS NULL) AND ((reserved_until IS NULL) OR (reserved_until <= '2021-05-14 14:23:16'::timestamp without time zone)))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 21704
Planning Time: 0.130 ms
Execution Time: 261.333 ms
```

---

I created the suggested index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON table_name (COALESCE(reserved_until, TIMESTAMP '-infinity'));
```

```
select *
from table_name
where rejected_at is null and COALESCE(reserved_until, TIMESTAMP '-infinity') <= '2021-05-14 14:23:16'
  and deleted_at is null
```

but the query plan selects `deleted_at` index for the updated query:
(development database)

```
Index Scan using table_name_deleted_at_index on table_name (cost=0.42..3277.19 rows=4845 width=938) (actual time=15.144..15.201 rows=48 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (deleted_at IS NULL)
"  Filter: ((rejected_at IS NULL) AND (COALESCE(reserved_until, '-infinity'::timestamp without time zone) <= '2021-05-14 14:23:16'::timestamp without time zone))"
  Rows Removed by Filter: 18633
Planning Time: 0.209 ms
Execution Time: 15.251 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the condition on `reserved_until` to

```
WHERE COALESCE(reserved_until, TIMESTAMP '-infinity') <= '2021-05-14 14:23:16'
```

and create an index for it:

```
CREATE INDEX ON table_name (COALESCE(reserved_until, TIMESTAMP '-infinity'))
   WHERE rejected_at IS NULL AND deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Then you should gather statistics:

```
ANALYZE table_name;
```

Comment: If I understand you right, the index in my modified answer should be the best fir for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is odd to see that it chooses `(deleted_at)` rather than `(rejected_at, deleted_at)`, it must be that `rejected_at` is usually NULL, so the condition on that is expected remove few rows.  The larger size of the index makes it thought to be not worth using to remove just a few more rows.

While a specialty index like the filtered functional index suggested in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/291587) may be optimal, a more general unfiltered index like `(deleted_at, reserved_until)` could also be good enough while still being usable over a wider range of other queries, and without requiring the queries to be written in an awkward style.

It would have to hit the index twice, once to get the NULL values of reserved_until and once for the `<` values of it, then combine them with a BitmapOr. See [Combining Multiple Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-bitmap-scans.html) in the manual and [Understanding "bitmap heap scan" and "bitmap index scan"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119386/understanding-bitmap-heap-scan-and-bitmap-index-scan) on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `(deleted_at)` index with

```
(deleted_at, rejected_at, reserved_until);
```

and remove any use of `COALESCE`